# Flask-SocketIO + Gevent: No logging, no backend requests going through

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Issue remains even through Postman requests, so I'm pretty sure it's purely a backend issue at this point. I have all the logging turned on, but all I have is a message confirming "Server initialized for gevent." If I send a request to my backend, it just hangs forever. No error codes, no nothing.

Works fine if I run it as a normal flask app/uninstall gevent-websocket, so I'm pretty sure it's the issue. Beyond that, I'm a little stumped.

Relevant Code:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'profile_pictures'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'}

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

CONNECTION = connect("testing", host=os.getenv("CONNECTION_STRING"))

app.config["JWT_ACCESS_LIFESPAN"] = {"hours": 24}
app.config["JWT_REFRESH_LIFESPAN"] = {"days": 30}
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

guard = flask_praetorian.Praetorian()

guard.init_app(app, user_class=User)

CORS(app, origins=["http://localhost:3000","https://jmsa-tutoring.netlify.app"])
socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True, cors_allowed_origins=["http://localhost:3000","site"], async_mode="gevent")

mail = Mail(app)

.
.
.
Routes
.
.
.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT'))
    socketio.run(app=app, use_reloader=True, port=port, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever wondered, this was another thing I also figured out myself. I had another priority import, so I didn't monkey patch gevent high enough. Cheers.